# How to resolve ImportError: No module named urls

Tags: django, django-urls, django-settings

I get this error whenever I run my code:

```
File "...", line 6, in <module> from django.urls import reverse    
ImportError: No module named urls
```

So I look at that file and check the line and it says that this has an error:

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

I don't know where the error is coming from because when I delete the line of code, it returns me this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I also tried adding MySQLdb in the interpreter but this time, it gives me this error:

```
Non-zero exit code (1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944378/django-from-django-urls-import-reverse-importerror-no-module-named-urls

Answer (score 0):

please confirm the `from django.conf.urls import include, url` is added in your header or not.

For MySQl error, you may need to install the Python and MySQL.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev #Ubuntu
```

Then install the mysql client using pip command.

```
pip install mysqlclient # for python 2.x

pip3 install mysqlclient # for python 3.x
```

Finally

```
pip install PyMySQL #for python 2.x 
pip3 install PyMySQL #for python 3.x
```

Comment: I'm using PyCharm and this is what it returned:

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: Based on your error I have describe the solution. Hope this link can help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944378/django-from-django-urls-import-reverse-importerror-no-module-named-urls

Comment: i tried your first solution [from django.conf.urls import include, url] and it worked.

but now, when I try to run it, it gives me the error of the mysqldb. when i try to install it via pycharm interpreter, its says Non-zero exit code (1)

Comment: try sudo pip install PyMySQL for python 2.x and sudo pip3 install PyMySQL for python3.x